# probability with bayesian theorem too many variables

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I have made the following list out from the text below:

- 1% of the students who made their homework forgot to turn it in **(A1)**
- 99% of the students who made their homework remembered to turn it in. **(B)**
- 90% of the students completed their homework on time. **(A2)**
- 10% did not complete their homework on time. **(A3)**
- 5% of those who did not complete their homework on time lied and said they forgot to turn it in. **(A4)**

From here I am stuck on how to calculate it. I have seen the Bayes Theorem but I seem to have too many variables?

> John tells his professor that he forgot to submit his homework
>   assignment. From experience, the professor knows that students who
>   finish their homework on time, actually forget to turn it in 1 in 100
>   times. She also knows that half of the students who have not finished
>   their homework will falsely tell her they forgot to turn it in. She
>   thinks that 90% of the students in this class completed their homework
>   on time. What is the probability that Jack is telling the truth, i.e.,
>   he finished it but forgot to submit it?

Possible answers to chose from:

- a. 0.059
- b. 0.1525
- c. 0.556

Comment: I'm rather sure it was you who asked the identical question the last time too.  My hint and suggestions are exactly the same.  Show us your work and **please answer each** of the leading questions I give you here.  Let us name the events $A$ and $B$.  What might you choose to be event $A$?  What might you choose to be event $B$?  What probability from those given correspond to $Pr(A)$?  $Pr(B)$?  $Pr(B\mid A)$? $Pr(B^c\mid A)$?  $Pr(B^c\mid A^c)$,  $Pr(B\mid A^c)$? etc...   Which pieces of information from $Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{Pr(B\mid A)Pr(A)}{Pr(B)}$ are you still missing?

Comment: Actually, your last item is either "$50\%$ of those who did not complete their homework on time lied and said they forgot to turn it in." or "$5\%$ of the students did not complete their homework and lied about it."

Comment: I edited my question. My problem here is that I have 4 different A's. That is why I don't know how to calculate it. The assignments I haave done before only had max 2-3.

Comment: @StudentCoderJava you are using far too many names and labels.  This can all be written with just $A$ and $B$ with no need for more than that, e.g. $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,\dots$.  See the beginnings below and see if you can continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup:**

Let $A$ represent the event "The homework was actually completed by the student" and event $B$ the event "The homework was not turned in but the student says they completed it"

We are told the following: $Pr(A)=0.9$, $Pr(B\mid A)=0.01$, $Pr(B\mid A^c)=0.5$ which immediately then implies the additional $Pr(A^c)=0.1$, $Pr(B^c\mid A)=0.99$, $Pr(B^c\mid A^c)=0.5$

(*note, $Pr(B\mid A^c)$ is $0.5$, not $0.05$ as per the phrase "She also knows that half of the students who have not finished their homework will falsely tell her they forgot to turn it in"*)

We wish to calculate $Pr(A\mid B)=\dfrac{Pr(B\mid A)Pr(A)}{Pr(B)}$

---

The next set of leading questions:

What piece or pieces of information from $Pr(A\mid B)=\dfrac{Pr(B\mid A)Pr(A)}{Pr(B)}$ are we still missing?

How might we go about calculating it?